# Вложенные проекты laravel

Tags: laravel

Подскажите как реализовать вложенность проектов laravel в проект laravel для их объединения.
У всех проектов своя структура, конфигурация, бд.
Я создал основной проект чистым laravel и назвал его projekt.com
Внутри создал две папки service1 и service2, туда перелил файлы сервисов.
В index.php переделал ссылки на

```
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Но при открытии url projekt.com/service1 или projekt.com/service2 он пытается найти route прописанные в корне projekt.com, route которые относятся к сервисам service1 и service2 он не видит.

Подскажите что я не так делаю или как реализуется такое размещение.

Comment: То есть вы хотите два проекта, но с одной установкой фреймворка?

Comment: Два проекта-сервиса со своими фреймворками, вложенные в главный фреймворк-информационная составляющая, откуда будет переход в проект-сервис.

Comment: это что-то типа микросервисов получается?

Comment: Да, каждый сервис независим со своей админкой, стилями, роутами. А сейчас он получается зависит от первого уровня то есть читает конфигурации фреймворка в который вложен.

Comment: Laravel больше для монолитной архитектуры подходит, по крайней мере я не видел ни одной нормальной реализации микросервисов на Laravel. В вашем случае можно попробовать сконфигурировать основной Laravel проект как прокси, который будет передавать запрос к другим проектам.

Answer (score 0):

То что вы хотите вполне можно реализовать с помощью **Laravel Packages** + **Гексагональная архитектура**.

Конкретно по вашей проблеме того что роуты не правильно читаются то нужно проверить следующее:

- Ларавел Package корректно установлен и зарегистрирован
- ServiceProvider пакета "service1" корректно загружается родительским проектом Ларавел
- В корне пакета "service1" имеется файл routes.php с описанным роутом "/service1"
- Внутри сервис провайдера пакета "service1" имеется код примерно такого вида:

```
    protected function packageDir(): string
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__) . '/';
    }

    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom($this->packageDir() . '/routes.php');
    }
```

**Подробнее все как это делать расписано тут:**

- Laravel Package Development - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages
- Как просто создать свой пакет Laravel - https://laravel.demiart.ru/package-development/
- Гексагональная архитектура - https://habr.com/ru/post/539084/

Но, конечно же, если не соблюдать чистую архитектуру то вложенные проекты станут сильно связанными с родительским проектом Laravel.